# Overriding/Disabling the max_length validation of CharField in form.ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-validation

Suppose I have this model defined in models.py:

```
[ . . . ]
class Robot(models.Model):
    ROBOT_CATEGORIES = (
    [ . . . ]
    )   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    version = models.ForeignKey('Version')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROBOT_CATEGORIES)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "ROBOT %s [%s]" % (self.name, self.version)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'version',)
```

I want to add Admin functionality to this model. User may enter a comma-separated-list of different Robot names, and `save_model` takes care of saving them as different objects. For this, I want to do *all* validation myself. So here is the Admin Code:

```
class RobotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
    comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

    def clean_name(self):
        # custom validation here
        [ . . . ]
        return data

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RobotForm, self).clean()
        # custom validation here
        [ . . . ]
        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = Robot

class RobotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RobotForm
    list_display = ('name','version','category','comments')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # custom save method
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(Robot, RobotAdmin);
```

Everything works fine, except for the `max_length` limit I set in the model for `Robot.name`. In the 'Add' form, if the list's length in the 'Name' field exceeds 30 chars, it flashes an error. I validate each individual name's length in the `clean_name` method, and want to disable the max_length validation in the form field. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In your overridden clean method remove the errors from the cleaned_data like here:

[Override data validation on one django form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340287/override-data-validation-on-one-django-form-element)

Comment: Hi Kugel. I am checking if `self._errors['name']` is set at the end of `RobotForm.clean()` method, but it is empty, so I can't `del` it. It is set by `CharField`'s `MaxLengthValidator`, which is probably called after call to `RobotForm`?

Comment: So, I guess I need to add the overrride in the model (the `clean` method of the model)? How do I get handle to the errors dict from Model's `clean`?

Comment: I don't think so, if your model is 30 chars max, than you database field is 30 char max. Use TextField in your model for unlimited string.

Comment: I made it work by explicitly making `name.validators = []` in `Robot`. It's really obscure hack, so I have put in some comments also. Thanks so much for your help :)