# Django forms.ChoiceField without validation of selected value

Tags: django

Django ChoiceField "Validates that the given value exists in the list of choices."

I want a ChoiceField (so I can input choices in the view) but I don't want Django to check if the choice is in the list of choices. It's complicated to explain why but this is what I need. How would this be achieved?

Comment: One way is to override the form validation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340287/override-data-validation-on-one-django-form-element

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could create a custom `ChoiceField` and override to skip validation:

```
class ChoiceFieldNoValidation(ChoiceField):
    def validate(self, value):
        pass
```

I'd like to know your use case, because I really can't think of any reason why you would need this.

Edit: to test, make a form:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    choice = ChoiceFieldNoValidation(choices=[('one', 'One'), ('two', 'Two')])
```

Provide "invalid" data, and see if the form is still valid:

```
form = TestForm({'choice': 'not-a-valid-choice'})
form.is_valid()  # True
```

Comment: Hey sorry, it did work. But I figured out an easier way to do it using forms.Charfield and a forms.Select widget. The problem was I forgot to manually re-populate the field on post, doh.

Comment: You got my up vote though :D  The validators solution was a no go for me. It still did the default validation anyways.

Comment: Just tested in 1.8.7, and it worked great. See my edit in the answer for how I tested it.

Comment: Tested in django 1.10, works fine. If you look at the source code there is no reason why it would not work https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py. When I tested though, **I had to restart the server** to get forms changes to apply. I feel like this is often the case

Comment: @jproffitt .. A possible use case is: in my form, I ask the the user to select the audio input source. The list of audio sources for the device can be collected via javascript with navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices(), so I prepare an empty select in the form, and populate it at runtime. The selection is then collected as usual after submission

Answer (score 23):

Best way to do this from the looks of it is create a `forms.Charfield` and use a `forms.Select` widget. Here is an example:

```
from django import forms

class PurchaserChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    floor = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Select(choices=[]))

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaserChoice
        fields = ['model', ]
```

For some reason overwriting the validator alone did not do the trick for me.

Comment: I would add as well that you should override the clean() method to validate it yourself based off of what you want. Doing this, you can have the choices be what you want, when you want and still have validation.

Comment: The floor will be blank when editing. That is not a reasonable option.

Answer (score 2):

As another option, you could write your own [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/)

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_all_choices(value):
    # here have your custom logic
    pass
```

and then in your form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.ChoiceField(validators=[validate_all_choices])
```

Edit: another option could be defining the field as a `CharField` but then render it manually in the template as a select with your choices. This way, it can accept everything without needing a custom validator

Comment: This did not work for me in django 1.6.5. It still seems to do the default validation as well.